# How to upload multipart file with product data in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

multipart file with product data in mvc model

```
   @PostMapping("/v1/save-product")
   
   public ProductDTO saveProductDTO(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
   throws IOException {

    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    
    return productService.saveProductDTO(productDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MultipartHttpServletRequest type to get your product dto and file.

```
  @PostMapping("/v1/save-product", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ProductDTO saveProductDTO(MultipartHttpServletRequest request ) throws IOException {

    ProductDTO productDTO = ObjectMapper.fromJson(request.getParameter("product", ProductDTO.class));

    MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> attachments = request.getMultiFileMap();

    attachments.forEach((key, multipartFiles) -> {
      multipartFiles.forEach(file -> {
        //do your all operations for each file and productDto.
        //like productService.saveProductDTO(productDTO);
      });
    });

    return null; //return your result
  }
```